# Aggregate data in one column before a date

Tags: r, dplyr, data.table

Am trying to sum value in another column that is grouped by ids. One id may have different accounts, which were opened on different days. I want to sum the amount before each account was opened i.e less than the date opened for each account. [here is the sample data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2REf7.png). The result should be this [This is the result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6Uynh.png). Note the sum_amount is sum of amount if there were any accounts that were opened before the account was opened.
Here is the sample code

```
id = c(1,1,1,2,2,2,2,3)
ac = c('a','z', 'k','d', 'g', 'f', 'w', 'h')
date_opened = c('2014-05-04','2014-03-01', '2014-06-01', '2014-04-01', '2014-06-01',
                '2014-03-01', '2014-01-01', '2014-01-01')
amount = c(200, 300,100, 400, 200, 50, 100, 200)
data <- data.frame(id, ac, date_opened, amount)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is to order your date and use cumsum (sumulative sum) on each id group. Here is the data table solution

```
data <- setDT(data)
data[,date_opened := as.Date(date_opened)]
setkey(data,date_opened)
data[,amountsum := cumsum(amount)- amount,by = id]
data[,.SD,by = id]
   id ac date_opened amount amountsum
1:  2  w  2014-01-01    100         0
2:  2  f  2014-03-01     50       100
3:  2  d  2014-04-01    400       150
4:  2  g  2014-06-01    200       550
5:  3  h  2014-01-01    200         0
6:  1  z  2014-03-01    300         0
7:  1  a  2014-05-04    200       300
8:  1  k  2014-06-01    100       500
```

and the dplyr solution

```
library(dplyr)
data %>%
  group_by(as.factor(id)) %>%
  arrange(date_opened) %>%
  mutate(amountsum = cumsum(amount)-amount)
```

Comment: look in the sample output and see if your output matches that.

Comment: I edited my answer, I didn't see you wanted to have the sum for the date only before. You just need to add - amount to the cumsum. Tell me if it works for you, accept the answer if it does

Comment: is it possible to count the number of accounts before the open date

Comment: with data table :`data[,countsum := cumsum(.GRP)- .GRP,by = id]` .With dplyr I dont know right now.